# Styling Iframe in PHP

Tags: php, css, iframe

How to style `iframe`? Nothing fancy, just want to override the browser CSS and remove the inset border.

```
foreach ($body_array as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($value, "www.youtube.com/watch?v=") !== false) {
        $link = preg_split("!&!", $value);
        $value = preg_replace("!watch\?v=!", "embed/", $link[0]);
        $value = "<br><iframe width=\'580\' height=\'315\' src=\'" . $value ."\'></iframe>";
        $body_array[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: use their api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: @EP19  posted an answer let me know if it helped using `frameborder="0"` , if i understood the question correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the border, you can use this within the `<iframe>` tag:

`frameborder="0"`

**Example**

```
<iframe id="if1" width="100%" height="254" frameborder="0" style="visibility:visible" src="https://www.test.com/"></iframe>
```

Can even add custom **border**

```
<iframe id="if1" width="100%" height="254" frameborder="0" style="visibility:visible; border: solid 4px #37474F;" src="https://www.test.com/"></iframe>
```

Amending for `php` :

```
foreach ($body_array as $key => $value) {
if(strpos($value, "www.youtube.com/watch?v=") !== false) {
    $link = preg_split("!&!", $value);
    $value = preg_replace("!watch\?v=!", "embed/", $link[0]);
    $value = "<br><iframe frameborder=\'0\' style=\'visibility:visible; border: solid 4px #37474F;\' width=\'580\' height=\'315\' src=\'" . $value ."\'></iframe>";
    $body_array[$key] = $value;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ylama - thanks for responding.  Yah I can't get it to pick it up in php...?  I tried these, tried attaching a class and id inline css, wtf?  I just keep getting the user agent syle sheet with ugly inset border.  iframe[Attributes Style] {
    width: 620px;
    height: 315px;
}
user agent stylesheet
iframe {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;

Comment: the width & height pick-up fine, but the frameborder keeps defaulting back to the agent user style sheet.

Comment: tell me if you view source code do you at least see the `frameborder="0"` inside the ifram tag, its not cached, you have tried it in incognito mode?

Comment: I do now @Ylama.  lol.  whenever your stuck on something it's always something stupid.  I was refreshing an existing video to no effect ;\ all new posts pick-up the frameborder.  works a treat - thankyou.